# How to specify width in px for cell?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sample code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style=" display: flex;">
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: #847"></div>
        <div class="container" style=" height: 50px; background-color: #147">
            <div class="row" style=" height: 20px; background-color: #997">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-2 " style=" height: 10px; background-color: #927"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style=" height: 10px; background-color: #947"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need:

1. 12 indented cells in the child rows(seems it works)
2. at the same time, have cell width in px for right cell (flex saves me, but i see some error when i reduce browser width until the end, in safari)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKXaoV

Help please, maybe it is not good solution and exists better one or how to fix? Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear to me

Comment: I agree, the question isn't exactly clear. I assume you want to have 12 indented cell in each child row (I've updated the question accordingly). Can you clarify?

Comment: @amadan, yes,12 cell in each child row and if is it possable have <div style='width:300px'><div class="row" 12 cells></div> without flex

Comment: If you need 12 cells, why doesn't the source show 12 divs.